# Помогите с сортировкой в обратном порядке

Tags: python, list, сортировка

Есть список элементов, который нужно отсортировать по последнему значению (Max Korn 98 - по числу в конце):

```
dogs = ['Cormen Alex 92',' Knuth Donald 98', 'ssad aospdopasd 99', 'Max Korn 98']
dogs = sorted(dogs, key=lambda points: points[-1])
dogs.reverse()
print(dogs)
```

Вот в такой комбинации вместо:

```
['ssad aospdopasd 99', ' Knuth Donald 98', ' Max Korn 98', 'Cormen Alex 92']
```

выдается:

```
['ssad aospdopasd 99', 'Max Korn 98', ' Knuth Donald 98', 'Cormen Alex 92']
```

То есть, Max и Knuth поменялись местами. Мне нужно сортировать по убыванию числовых значений.

Просто добавить `reverse=True`  не подойдет, тогда значения с одинаковыми баллами поменяются местами, чего бы мне не хотелось.

Comment: а где список элементов? приведите кусок своего кода с исходными данными в вопросе.

Comment: Список элементов 
---
dogs = ['Cormen Alex 92',' Knuth Donald 98', 'ssad aospdopasd 99', 'Max Korn 98']
---
Кусок кода тот же - dogs = sorted(dogs, key=lambda points: points[-1])

Comment: dogs = ['Cormen Alex 92',' Knuth Donald 98', 'ssad aospdopasd 99', 'Max Korn 98']
dogs = sorted(dogs, key=lambda points: points[-1])
dogs.reverse()
print(dogs)

Вот в такой комбинации вместо ['ssad aospdopasd 99', ' Knuth Donald 98', ' Max Korn 98', 'Cormen Alex 92'] - выдается ['ssad aospdopasd 99', 'Max Korn 98', ' Knuth Donald 98', 'Cormen Alex 92']
То есть max и knuth поменялись местами

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам надо разделить строку по пробелам и преобразовать в число последний элемент результата

```
print(sorted(lst, key=lambda x: -int(x.split()[-1])))
```